# How to make Contextual Action Bar to appear at the bottom

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar, android-actionmode, android-cab

I have created an activity and set  toolbar as the actionbar which i have positioned at the bottom.

Inside that activity, I have a listview that contain some data.

Problem is, when I long press a list item, contextual action bar appears at the top instead of overlaying my toolbar which is positioned at the bottom.

**my activity theme**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="myActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

**my toolbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toorbar"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**my activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ToolBar toolbar =(ToolBar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}
```

This is `onCreateActionMode` method in my  class that handle long clicks

```
private class Selector implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_activity_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }
```

What should i do to make CAB appear at the bottom?

Comment: Hey, I know this question is too old. But, I stumbled across the same situation and I can't seem to find any help. If you have the solution, can you please help me?

Comment: @AnirudhdhsinhJadeja Kuffs answer below that contain the github link was a good guide for me. try it out

Comment: I know. It's a good guide. But, I am java developer. And when I tried to implement it in java, editor just says can't resolve the symbol. even after implementing the dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your own CAB with a Toolbar. You can then put it wherever you like.

This project should give you a head start.

https://github.com/afollestad/material-cab

Comment: It's been a long time but the above project is a good guide. I can't even remember why I was putting the toolbar at the bottom. :)

Comment: Hey, will this work in java too? I can't seem to find the functions mentioned in java.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>

        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>

        <!-- required for toolbar in prelolipop -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        **<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>**

    </style>
```

use `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay>true</item>` for Contextual action bar to overlay toolbar. And remove if you have used
`<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`. It worked for me.

Comment: It's a long time but the problem was that my toolbar was at the bottom of an activity thus even adding `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay>true</item>` could not help. I can't remember even why I was putting the toolbar at the bottom.